# NSPredicate usage

Tags: iphone

I am having string @"King (+$100)".I want to use NSPredicate to find if string is having (+$[0-9]*).So how to use NSPrdicate

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to determine if the digits 0-9 are in a string?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// The string to evaluate
NSString *string = @"King (+$100)";

// The regular expression
NSString *regExp =  @".*\\(\\+\\$[0-9]*\\).*";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",regExp];

// Test if the object checks the regular expression 
BOOL ok = [predicate evaluateWithObject:string];
```

For all documentation on the NSPredicate see:
[NSPredicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html)

Comment: Thanks.I got it.One more thing is that how get to that particular string.if the pattern matches i.e [predicate evaluateWithObject:string]; if this fuction retuns true is there way to get using NSPredicate (+$100).

Comment: I don't know how to do that with the standard API. I have searched, but nothing...
So I guess that you'll have to work with the NSString and/or the NSScanner to find your occurrence.